# how to convert date into unix time in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unix-timestamp

I have a date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and want to convert this in UNIX time in snowflake.

Function does this is MySQL:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('1999-01-22')
```

MySQL output `916988400`

How can I achieve the same in snowflake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the date_part function with epoch_second for the part:

```
select date_part(epoch_second, '1999-01-22'::timestamp);
```